# UIBarButtonItem not changing colour

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I have a bar button item in my navigation bar, which is the integrated 'Add' choice. It has the colour R:22/255, G:40/255, B:86/255, which is a dark blue colour. This button has been connected with a segue.

When I run my project, I cannot see the button, but when I press the place where it may be, the `UITableViewController` it segues to is presented.

Now, when I change the button type to any other choice, such as 'Done', the button appears, but now my table view is blacked out (note that it is only the table view blacked out, not the navigation bar/tab bar).

There is nothing obvious overriding this.

How can I use the 'Add' option, with the colour appearing?

Of course, most of this is not programmed, as it's in the `Main.storyboard`, but here is my code corresponding to the navigation bar appearance.

```
// Adding image to Navigation Bar
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named:"pinpoint.png")!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate))
    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    navigationItem.titleView = imageView
    imageView.tintColor = UIColor(red: 22.0/255.0, green: 40.0/255.0, blue: 86.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    // Removing hairline under Navigation Bar
    for parent in self.navigationController!.navigationBar.subviews {
        for childView in parent.subviews {
            if(childView is UIImageView) {
                childView.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }

    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 22.0/255.0, green: 40.0/255.0, blue: 86.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

Comment: r,g,b should be between 0.0 - 1.0.

Comment: @LeoDabus It's out of 255 in my code, but I left this out in the question, as I thought that it would be obvious. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: please post your code

Comment: @Masterfego Have now.